# Looking to import data from an api to create a grid using react-virtualized

Tags: react-virtualized

I'm a  super noob to react, and looking to take advantage of react-virtualized for a hobby project.

What's the quickest way to get started with react-virtualized? I've tried create-react-app and NPM install react-virtualized, but as soon as I start adding new data I run into issues. any advice?

Eventually I'm looking to grab API data and render it into a live grid with data from CoinCap to show live cryptocurrency prices. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated too!

Answer (score 0):

> but as soon as I start adding new data I run into issues. any advice?

I don't think anyone could provide advice without more information than you've provided.

Using create-react-app is a great first step. As for react-virtualized, check out [the docs](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/) (which generally show [some basic examples](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Grid.md#basic-grid-example) of how to use each component) and look at the source for one of the examples on [the demo site](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List) (like [this `Grid` example](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Grid/Grid.example.js)).

I suggest forking one of the "official" examples and then- if you run into problems- come back here and provide specific information about what went wrong so people can help. You may also try the [react-virtualized Slack support channel](https://react-virtualized.now.sh/).